# Unable to click element Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to be able to click a certain element with selenium.
I am using the following link : https://www.rivm.nl/media/smap/eenzaamheid.html

I want to be able to select each and every county/province within the map with a for loop.

The map itself I located with:

```
wijk_keuze = WebDriverWait(driver2nd,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='highcharts-container ']//*[name()='svg']")
```

so far so good. However when I want to select a county/province this is where my problems start.

The counties/provinces live in the following element:

```
<g class="highchairs-series-group">
```

within this parent element I want to loop through each child element (being the counties/provinces).
The counties/provinces elements look like this:

```
<g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-map-series  highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(79,10) scale(1 1)" style="cursor:pointer;" clip-path="url(#highcharts-5p0c896-1)" role="region" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Delfzijl, series 1 of 4. Map with 0 areas.">
```

every county-element looks the same except the aria-label. (Delfzijl is an example of a county/province)

I was able to locate the "download-element" on the map, so I assumed to follow a similar process. The download element is located and clicked by doing the following:

```
    Indicator_keuze.select_by_index(index)
    download = WebDriverWait(driver2nd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='highcharts-container ']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @aria-label='View export menu']//*[name()='rect']")))  
    download.click()
    WebDriverWait(download, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='highcharts-menu']//*[contains(text(),'XLS downloaden')]"))).click()
```

I tried locating the above element by doing the following:

```
wijk_keuze = WebDriverWait(driver2nd,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='highcharts-container ']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and aria-label='Delfzijl, series 1 of 4. Map with 0 areas.']")))
```

This however results in a time out error.

So, how would I be able to loop through and click on each different county/province?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of comments I could make here, but the main one might be:

<g class=
[name()='g'

This won't match. Name looks for the attribute name="", i.e. <div name="g"

Comment: Reason that I am using "name ='g'" is that is used this while locating the download element (I edited my question, please see question for further explanation) which worked. So I assumed following a similar process would work as well. Any fixes or solutions?

Comment: I have it working so that I can click the first region (With name()='g', so this does work) Any clue how I could then loop through each element within the parent element? (the code:  wijk_keuze = WebDriverWait(driver2nd,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='highcharts-container ']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='path']")))
    wijk_keuze.click()